# Static library breaks build

Tags: xcode, mono, xamarin.ios, pinvoke, static-libraries

I've compiled a static library targetting 'iOS Device' in xcode and have linked it to a monotouch app. When I build and run the app I immediately get an error:

> Mono.Debugger.Soft.VMDisconnectedException: Exception of type
>   'Mono.Debugger.Soft.VMDisconnectedException' was thrown.   at
>   Mono.Debugger.Soft.Connection.SendReceive (CommandSet command_set,
>   Int32 command, Mono.Debugger.Soft.PacketWriter packet) [0x00000] in
>   :0    at Mono.Debugger.Soft.Connection.VM_GetVersion
>   () [0x00000] in :0    at
>   Mono.Debugger.Soft.Connection.Connect () [0x00000] in :0    at Mono.Debugger.Soft.VirtualMachine.connect ()
>   [0x00000] in :0    at
>   Mono.Debugger.Soft.VirtualMachineManager.ListenInternal
>   (System.Net.Sockets.Socket dbg_sock, System.Net.Sockets.Socket
>   con_sock) [0x00000] in :0

And there is no application output. It doesn't seem to matter if I sign or don't sign the library, I've tried various versions and build settings even switching out between compilers (last compiler I used was the stock GCC 4.2 compiler). Whm

When I build the library for a simulator and link it to the app to run on the device it actually runs on the device, but as soon as a function is p/invoked the app quits and I get system output explaining the pinvoke was unable to be resolved.

The reason this isn't running may be because of build setting or something somewhere , since it runs on the simulator it could be a JIT vs. AOT issue.'

edit:

This is the C# side of things:

```
        [DllImport("__Internal")]
        private static extern int CreateWorld(b2Vec2 grav, OnIOSContact startContact, ContactOver endContact);

    delegate bool OnIOSContact(MyCollisionEvent ev);
    delegate bool ContactOver(MyCollisionEvent ev);

    [MonoTouch.MonoPInvokeCallback(typeof(OnIOSContact))]
    static bool StatContactStart(MyCollisionEvent ev){...}

    [MonoTouch.MonoPInvokeCallback(typeof(ContactOver))]
    static bool StatContactEnd(MyCollisionEvent ev){...}


    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Size=8),Serializable]
    struct MyCollisionEvent
    {
        public IntPtr ActorA;
        public IntPtr ActorB;
    }




    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Size=8),Serializable]
    public struct b2Vec2
    {
        public b2Vec2(float _x, float _y)
        {
            x = _x;
            y = _y;
        }
        public float x;
        public float y;
    }
```

and the C code behind it:

```
       extern "C"
       int CreateWorld(b2Vec2 gravity, bool (*startContact)(Contact), bool (*endContact)(Contact))

 //contact struct to match MyCollisionEvent in C# code
 typedef struct
 {
     b2Body *bodyA;
     b2Body *bodyB;
 }Contact;

/// A 2D column vector.
struct b2Vec2
{
    /// Default constructor does nothing (for performance).
    b2Vec2() {}

    /// Construct using coordinates.
    b2Vec2(float32 x, float32 y) : x(x), y(y) {}

    /// Set this vector to all zeros.
    void SetZero() { x = 0.0f; y = 0.0f; }

    /// Set this vector to some specified coordinates.
    void Set(float32 x_, float32 y_) { x = x_; y = y_; }

    /// Negate this vector.
    b2Vec2 operator -() const { b2Vec2 v; v.Set(-x, -y); return v; }

    /// Read from and indexed element.
    float32 operator () (int32 i) const
    {
        return (&x)[i];
    }

    /// Write to an indexed element.
    float32& operator () (int32 i)
    {
        return (&x)[i];
    }

    /// Add a vector to this vector.
    void operator += (const b2Vec2& v)
    {
        x += v.x; y += v.y;
    }

    /// Subtract a vector from this vector.
    void operator -= (const b2Vec2& v)
    {
        x -= v.x; y -= v.y;
    }

    /// Multiply this vector by a scalar.
    void operator *= (float32 a)
    {
        x *= a; y *= a;
    }

    /// Get the length of this vector (the norm).
    float32 Length() const
    {
        return b2Sqrt(x * x + y * y);
    }

    /// Get the length squared. For performance, use this instead of
    /// b2Vec2::Length (if possible).
    float32 LengthSquared() const
    {
        return x * x + y * y;
    }

    /// Convert this vector into a unit vector. Returns the length.
    float32 Normalize()
    {
        float32 length = Length();
        if (length < b2_epsilon)
        {
            return 0.0f;
        }
        float32 invLength = 1.0f / length;
        x *= invLength;
        y *= invLength;

        return length;
    }

    /// Does this vector contain finite coordinates?
    bool IsValid() const
    {
        return b2IsValid(x) && b2IsValid(y);
    }

    float32 x, y;
};
```

Edit 2:

I should have mentioned this when I first wrote the post but I have been able to get the app running on the device a few times. Typically it involved revuilding the project/library with slightly different build settings (such as signing the library) but I haven't been able to discern the steps needed to be taken which causes these successful builds...

Each time it  did run it crashed out (due to unrelated bugs) but even slight modification to code (such as commenting out a line) caused the same error to pop up again. Even restoring the line wouldn't make the error go away.

Comment: Can you edit your post to include the p/invoke signature in both C# (including the attributes) and C ? thanks

Comment: done. That is the specific function called (it's also the first one to be pinked). I'm not sure if it should even work on a device if the library is built for a simulator.

Comment: Please also include the managed/native definition of non-primitive types, e.g. b2Vec2, Contact, OnIOSContact and ContactOver. It's likely that your random crashes are caused by a mishandling the stack when the managed/native representation does not match.

Comment: ok done, I think that's all the relevant code :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much pain I decided I'd do a clean install of iOS on the iPhone and that fixed up the errors. I'm still not quite sure what was causing the errors but since a clean iOS install fixed it I can only assume it had something to do with the previous install and was hopefully very specific to that one install.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything obvious. Try a divide an conquer approach, i.e.

- remove the code using any method parameters; then
- remove one (after the other) parameters (e.g. first b2Vec2, then the callbacks...)

until you reach a (solidly, never crashing) working point. That will make a smaller test case to check :)

Comment: ok I just tried it again removing all extern "C" functions and C# functions attempting to invoke those extern "C" functions. Just linking the lib in without ever invoking any functions inside it anywhere in code.

 I'm still getting the same issue. I did find if I rebuild the lib and drag it over the existing lib being linked in then rebuilding the entire solution, compiling and running the app would actually run, but then it would complain about not being able to find a file. If I just don't link the lib in it finds the file and runs fine...

Comment: I dug up the crash log and paste binned it here: http://pastebin.com/7rYzmRBk (if that helps...)

Comment: I don't see how it would crash if the C# code does not call the library anymore (it should not need the C/C++ code to be changed). Could you symbolicate your crash report and/or run "/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/bin/mtouch --logdev" after the crash (and copy/paste the last part related to the crash). Thanks

Comment: THis is the last bit of output from runnning mtouch --logdev: http://pastebin.com/GVc78ata

Comment: In regards to the symbolicated crash report I assume you mean this: http://jabberworx.net/ChicksnVixens_2011-08-17-235154_JabberWorx.crash

Comment: I ran the app again from a clean build and got a slightly different crash log: http://jabberworx.net/ChicksnVixens_2011-08-18-001708_JabberWorx.crash (this is with slightly different build settings).

Comment: There's nothing in --logdev (and there should be when a crash occurs on the device, maybe it's was earlier in the log?!?). Can you try again, i.e. run/crash app in device then post the --logdev output

Comment: ok tried it again (ran the app, it crashed with the same error), here's the entire output from terminal: http://pastebin.com/iSJaX4Ze Perhaps the issue has nothing to do with mono?

Comment: ok, this time your logs showed the crash. Here's the part I was looking for: http://pastebin.com/g02UmdWT

Comment: @meds let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2583/discussion-between-poupou-and-meds)